# Unable to get value back from directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options

I've got this directive

```
app.directive('countrySelect', function (Country) {
return {
    templateUrl: 'template/directives/countryselect.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        selectedValue: '='
    },
    link: function (scope) {
        Country.success(function (data) {
            scope.countries = data;
        });
    }
}
});
```

my template

```
<select chosen
    data-placeholder="Country"
    search-contains="true"
    ng-model="selectedValue"
    ng-options="name as country.name for country in countries">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
```

I've set the model to be the selectedValue but I only get undefined back when I try to console.log it.

Here's the HTML where I use my directive

```
<country-select selected-value="custCtrl.editForm.country"></country-select>
```

and console logging the variable custCtrl.editForm.country just gives undefined.

I thought "=" was two way data binding?
What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: The variable you pass to the directive must be an object. Have you ascertained that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-options` syntax is wrong.  The 1st term in that syntax represents the option value, and is therefore the value that `ng-model` will mirror. You've specified a variable called `name` which is in fact undefined.  It should be `country.name`:

```
ng-options="country.name as country.name for country in countries"
```

(The 2nd `country.name` specifies the option label, i.e. the text shown in the dropdown list.  This does not need to match the 1st term, but often will.)

---

**DEMO:**  [Here is a fiddle you can play around with](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/n0a7ghno/)

In it, you will see that there are watches which log to the console from both the controller and the directive whenever the model changes.  The controller also displays the selected value in the HTML.  (I added `$scope` to the controller for the watch but you don't need it in production.)